# How to create Exchange 2013/16 Mail flow rules based on domain

Tags: exchange-server

I am trying to set up Send Connector to achieve the following;

1- I have multiple domains and send outbound via multiple smarthost/IPs

2- I want to be able to create sender connector based on domain i.e if the sender/domains is example.com use this smarthost/IP or if domain is domain.com use diffrent smarthost/IPs

I know i can do this via Office 365 but couldn't do it in On-prem

Chers

Answer (score 0):

Exchange server cannot do that natively. Google for "RouteBySender for Exchange 2013/2016/2019".